# Is it worth defining \ensuretext ?

Tags: macros, text-mode

We already have `\ensuremath` to make sure the argument get enclosed in math mode. Is it worth defining `\ensuretext` ?

Comment: `\def\ensuretext#1{\ensuremath{$#1$}}`

Comment: @Seamus: `\ensuremath` must not enclose a pair of `$`s.

Comment: Would `\ensuremath{\)#1\(}` work?

Comment: @Seamus: I cannot down vote your comments :)

Comment: Ugh. I just tried `$x^2\)` which compiles fine... (Though it breaks emacs syntax highlighting...)

Comment: @Seamus: No. How do you use it in a `equation` environment?

Comment: As far as I know, the only_safe_ way to ensure text mode is to use an `\hbox`. I've tried various inverse versions of `\ensuremath`, and they fail too often to be recommended.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think `amsmath`'s `\text` is just OK.

---

Quoted from document of `amstext`:

> The `\text` macro is a sophisticated command which allows
>   the user to insert “normal text” into math formulas without worrying about
>   correct sizes in sub- or superscripts. It can also be used in ordinary text; there
>   it produces an unbreakable unit similar to `\mbox`.

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK there is no `\ensuretext` because a simple `\hbox` or `\mbox` is enforcing text mode already. However, if you need automatic scaling for subscripts etc. then use Leo's answer which handles this.

BTW there is the `\ifmmode` switch to test if you are in mathmode. It is used by e.g. `\text`.